# C# How to Load .mtl with obj

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, textures, helix-3d-toolkit

I am trying to load .obj files with mtl files which are in the same folder and have always the same name.

Actually I can load obj file and see the object in the view but without the mtl file (textures)

My Code for the obj loader in the open file dialog looks like this :

```
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            obj_name.Text = filename;

            ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();
            Model3DGroup model1 = import.Load(dlg.FileName);
            model.Content = model1; here
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Where is `ModelImporter` from?

Comment: It´s from HelixToolKit

Comment: From a quick look in the Helix code, this looks ok. Are your model files valid? What format do the textures have? Can you try to use the `ObjReader` directly and see if it has reasonable [Materials](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/072dd90a99825ded57424c05fded621f65709dfb/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf/Importers/ObjReader.cs#L127)?

Comment: Texture file is valid. I just don´t know how to load the mtl file in the same path.